# Any mindmap software that supports code, latex, and pictures?

Tags: windows, mind-mapping

I have tried:

- Xmind: only supports pictures
- Freeplane: supports latex and pictures, but doesn't support code.

There is only one online mindmap that fits my requirements:

- supports markdown (which means supports code)
- support latex
- can paste picture into it

The mindmap looks like:

[image: example mindmap]

But I don't like to use an online service.

Is there any recommendation for a Windows GUI application?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what features do you need, what OS should it run on, how much might it cost.

Comment: @Izzy♦ It is quite appearant  in my opinion, the title already gave all the points .I think you mean people doesn't know code, latex and mindmap meannings ?  If you ask me what I don't know, I can't give you the answer , so I didn't add the explanation for those keywords .  Now they have be added :) .

Comment: No. But how should they guess e.g. Windows (looks like our Lizard knew the two other apps you've mentioned, and they are Win-only), for example? Or your workflow (maybe you meant to generate a workflow from Latex/Markdown input? The clearer the better ;)